# Configuring SSL certificate off-load when dealing with Azure web app behind Application Gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have set up an application gateway(AG) to eventually protect my web app using [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/02/15/web-app-with-vnet-only-access-using-app-gateway-powershell-automation/#comment-99125) but with the difference that the AG's public IP will forward the requests to my web app and I won't be using any jump box.

[This diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50kKe.png) should give you a better idea.

Now on my web app, I have added couple of domains under the Custom domains and I don't have any SSL binding thinking that the AG will do the work. Basically I have added the SSL cert to the AG's Front End IP--->Listener. I also redirect the HTTP to HTTPs on AG using the listeners, and on the web app I am not forcing HTTPS.

My questions are:

1. Is this roughly the right way to protect a web app (Please note that in the future I intend to enable WAF and the DDOS protection on AG)?
2. Is having the AG do the encryption/decryption going to slow things down?

**EDIT**: I actually removed the two domains from the web app's custom domains and it seems to work fine without it but I still have the above two questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, this is the way of doing it, if you want to can configure end-to-end ssl (a bit more secure)
2. Obviously it will, but negligible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just a clarification about point 2. I meant between the AG and Webapp, does it make any difference which one will be doing the SSL bit?

Comment: well, makes more sense to offload on application gateway. since this relieves some cpu pressure on the webapp